# Pandas Add a List to New Column or Append at the End

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am adding new lists to a column of a dataframe of pandas. Since i am doing this in a loop, I want to first create a new column and put some values inside this column. Then, over other loop, I am adding new values to the column which is just created. How can I do this?

I have a python list named all_material_percentages

```
All Material Percentages:
[0.660377358490566, 0.34285714285714286, ... 1.5151515151515151, 1.12, 0.5892857142857143]
```

```
>>> len(all_material_percentages)
48
>>> len(total_parameter_number)
2
>>> len(total_year_number)
2
>>> print(input_material_name)
['Cold Sheet Iron', 'Hot Sheet Iron']
```

My trial is:

```
for i in range(total_parameter_number):
    for j in range(total_year_number):        
        output[input_material_name[i]) = pd.Series(all_material_percentages[i*12+(12*j*total_parameter_number):(i*12)+12+(12*j*total_parameter_number)])
```

Then I write output to an excel file:
[excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZWaC.png)

I am aware of the problem that output(input_material_name[i]) is overwritten, but I do not know how to solve this. I tried append, insert functions, but I could not find a way to do this.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a more pythonic way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# first initialize your data frame with the columns
# columns with empty data has been initialized, now you can just add data to it 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=input_material_name)

# to avoid any confusion I would advise you to first build the list of data for your different columns and at the end just add it to the dataframe

# here 'i' is the index returned by enumerate 
for i, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    for j in range(total_year_number):        
        df[column] = all_material_percentages[i*12+(12*j*total_parameter_number):(i*12)+12+(12*j*total_parameter_number)])

# for writing to excel file
df.to_excel('file.xls')
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if I missed something or you want to do something different.